# Using js remove comma from number from existing data

Tags: javascript

The array data is

```
[{
  "Date": "2018-03-20",
  "Total": "10,459"
}, {
  "Date": "2018-03-21",
  "Total": "11,947"
}, {
  "Date": "2018-03-22",
  "Total": "12,932",
}];
```

And I need to be like this:

```
[{
  "Date": "2018-03-20",
  "Total": "10459"
}, {
  "Date": "2018-03-21",
  "Total": "11947"
}, {
  "Date": "2018-03-22",
  "Total": "12932",
}];
```

Comment: Please show us what have you tried so far. Are you stuck on some specific step when implementing this?

Comment: @lonut i have only this json the things i done its fine now what i have to do is to remove comma from number inside total.

Comment: https://www.google.nl/search?q=remove+comma+json+values+javascript+site:stackoverflow.com

Comment: Since it's a string, just use a simple `.replace()`. For the record, this is a good example of why we save integers as actual integers instead of some language based string, since doing that would avoid this entire problem. ( and probably other problems not asked about )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [String.prototype.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)
 to modify the property `Total`:

```js
var data = [{"Date": "2018-03-20", "Total": "10,459"},{"Date": "2018-03-21", "Total": "11,947"},{"Date": "2018-03-22", "Total": "12,932",}];

data = data.map(i => {
  i.Total = i.Total.replace(/,/g,'');
  return i;
});
console.log(data);
```

Comment: Your json is not json, it is just a javascript object array

Comment: @mamun thanks it works :)

Comment: @PrakashPandey, you are most welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.map` for this and inside its callback replace the comma

```js
const x = [{
  "Date": "2018-03-20",
  "Total": "10,459"
}, {
  "Date": "2018-03-21",
  "Total": "11,947"
}, {
  "Date": "2018-03-22",
  "Total": "12,932",
}];

const y = x.map(el => {
  el.Total = el.Total.replace(/,/g, "");
  return el;
})

console.log(y);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution would be to use `parseFloat`:

```
 const data = [{
      "Date": "2018-03-20",
      "Total": "10,459"
    }, {
      "Date": "2018-03-21",
      "Total": "11,947"
    }, {
      "Date": "2018-03-22",
      "Total": "12,932",
    }];  

      data.map(row => {
          row.Total = parseFloat(row.Total.replace(/,/g, ''));
        })
```

Comment: `row.Total = +(row.Total.replace(/,/g, ''));`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `map` function and the `replace` function to remove the commas from the `Total`

```js
let data = [{
  "Date": "2018-03-20",
  "Total": "10,459"
}, {
  "Date": "2018-03-21",
  "Total": "11,947"
}, {
  "Date": "2018-03-22",
  "Total": "12,932",
}];

let res = data.map(elem => {
  elem.Total = elem.Total.replace(',', '');
  return elem;
})

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Using JQuery**

```js
var data=[{
  "Date": "2018-03-20",
  "Total": "10,459"
}, {
  "Date": "2018-03-21",
  "Total": "11,947"
}, {
  "Date": "2018-03-22",
  "Total": "12,932",
}];
$.each(data,function(index,item){
  item.Total=item.Total.replace(",","");
   console.log(item);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

use `$.each` to iterate over an object.

Comment: `$.each()` => `data.forEach()` JQuery isn't mentioned anywhere in the question.